# Commuting group matrices

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $G$ be a group and form the associated Hilbert space $\ell^2(G)$ with canonical orthonormal basis $(e_g)_{g\in G}$. For $g \in G$, define the operators $u_g, v_g ∈ B(\ell^2(G))$ by
$$u_g(e_h) := e_{gh}\ ,\ v_g(e_h) := e_{hg^{−1}}, \ \forall \ h\in G$$
Consider the generated von Neumann algebras $A := \overline{\{u_g : g \in G\}}^{WOT}$ and $B := \overline{\{v_g : g \in G\}}^{WOT}$.

How to prove that the commutant $A′= B$ ? From a characterization of a matrix in $A'$.

We can characterize that $a= (a_{fh})_{f,h\in G}$, an operator given by its matrix, commutes with all of the $u_g$'s if and only if $$\forall g,f,h\in G \ :\ a_{gf\ gh}= a_{f\ h}$$
The matrix of $a$ should be constant on 'diagonals' ( provided we view $h\mapsto gh$ as a translation ).

But how to show that this $a$ is a [WOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_operator_topology)-limit of $v_g$'s ?

Or is there another approach?

Comment: Formally, $a=\sum_{g\in G} a_{e,g}v_g$. The difficult part is to show that sum exists as a WOT limit.

Comment: Can you explicit how you manage to find this expression for $a$? What I get is $a=\sum_g \lambda_g u_g$

Comment: Both sides give the same result when plugged into $\langle \delta_s,\cdot\,\delta_t\rangle$ for $s,t\in G$.

Comment: can you also give a hint on the difficult inclusion? showing that this sum can be a WOT limit.

Comment: Not really, unfortunately. I know how to prove this in a more general setting, but it takes some work, and I don't see a slick trick to make it easier for group von Neumann algebras. If you don't get an answer here, take a look at Theorem 7.1.1 here: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/Books/IIunV15.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Actually Theorem 1.3.6 solves it, still the details are more than a one page argument and convolutions have to be introduced !

Comment: Yes, I think the argument is basically the same as for Theorem 7.1.1.